# Css Text Animation maybe and some javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, frontend

Basically, I want to reach this but I don't really know-how.
Some examples or videos would help a lot.

The Animation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLXva.gif

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exaclty looking for but this might be a good start:
[Animate.css](https://animate.style/)

> Animate.css is a library of ready-to-use, cross-browser animations for use in your web projects. Great for emphasis, home pages, sliders, and attention-guiding hints.

## Basic usage

> After installing Animate.css, add the class animate__animated to an element, along with any of the animation names (don't forget the animate__ prefix!):

```html
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce">An animated element</h1>
That's it! You've got a CSS animated element. Super!
```

## Snippet

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="animate__animated animate__flipInX">An animated element</h1>
</body>

</html>
```